# Time needed to obtain RGB values of pictures

Tags: python, image, rgb, profiler

I wrote a piece of code to obtain the RGB value at a given location in images and was surprised by how long it took.
Here is the code I used:

```
path ="Images/"
listFiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
listFiles.sort()
rgbValue = np.zeros((len(listFiles), 3))
start = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(50):
    for index, file in enumerate(listFiles):
        im = Image.open(path+file)
        pix = im.load()
        rgbValue[index, :] = pix[50, 50]  # Get the RGBA Value of the a pixel of an image in the position 50, 50
        im.close()
end = timeit.default_timer()
print("Done in {} s. Average time is {} s.".format(end-start, (end-start)/50))
```

I worked with a set of (dog) images from Google Images. There are 68 images for a total of ~500 kb. Given that I go 50 times through the data set, I work with 4300 images and about 2.5 Mb.
And this took between 3 and 4 seconds!

Consequently I used cProfile to see where the bottleneck could be in my code. I put the main part in a function, called pxValues, then called it from cProfile:

```
def pxValues():
    for i in range(50):
        for index, file in enumerate(listFiles):
            im = Image.open(path+file)
            pix = im.load()
            rgbValue[index, :] = pix[50, 50] 
            im.close()
    return True

cProfile.run('pxValues()')

    615404 function calls in 3.655 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.075    0.075    3.655    3.655 <ipython-input-5-ccab4473739f>:1(pxValues)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.655    3.655 <string>:1(<module>)
     3400    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 BmpImagePlugin.py:49(_accept)
     3400    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 GifImagePlugin.py:38(_accept)
     3400    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 Image.py:2492(_decompression_bomb_check)
     3400    0.024    0.000    0.702    0.000 Image.py:2512(open)
     3400    0.019    0.000    0.350    0.000 Image.py:2556(_open_core)
     3400    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 Image.py:358(preinit)
     3400    0.010    0.000    0.019    0.000 Image.py:418(_getdecoder)
     3400    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 Image.py:519(__init__)
     3400    0.022    0.000    0.036    0.000 Image.py:560(close)
     3400    0.003    0.000    0.005    0.000 Image.py:586(__del__)
     6800    0.006    0.000    0.009    0.000 Image.py:794(load)
     3400    0.059    0.000    2.837    0.001 ImageFile.py:130(load)
     3400    0.005    0.000    0.062    0.000 ImageFile.py:259(load_prepare)
     3400    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 ImageFile.py:268(load_end)
    27200    0.010    0.000    0.016    0.000 ImageFile.py:522(_safe_read)
     3400    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 ImageFile.py:66(_tilesort)
     3400    0.013    0.000    0.298    0.000 ImageFile.py:78(__init__)
     3400    0.033    0.000    0.047    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:151(SOF)
     3400    0.025    0.000    0.033    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:199(DQT)
     3400    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:292(_accept)
     3400    0.068    0.000    0.275    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:304(_open)
     3400    0.002    0.000    0.007    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:418(_getmp)
     3400    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:481(_getmp)
    17000    0.016    0.000    0.037    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:52(Skip)
     3400    0.026    0.000    0.041    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:57(APP)
     3400    0.013    0.000    0.317    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:763(jpeg_factory)
     3400    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 TiffImagePlugin.py:252(_accept)
     3400    0.003    0.000    0.011    0.000 __init__.py:1284(debug)
     3400    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 __init__.py:1528(getEffectiveLevel)
     3400    0.004    0.000    0.008    0.000 __init__.py:1542(isEnabledFor)
    81600    0.015    0.000    0.015    0.000 _binary.py:23(i8)
    74800    0.029    0.000    0.054    0.000 _binary.py:71(i16be)
     6800    0.005    0.000    0.009    0.000 _util.py:13(isPath)
     3400    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 _util.py:23(__init__)
     3400    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {built-in method PIL._imaging.jpeg_decoder}
     3400    0.057    0.000    0.057    0.000 {built-in method PIL._imaging.new}
    74800    0.025    0.000    0.025    0.000 {built-in method _struct.unpack}
     3400    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method builtins.divmod}
        1    0.000    0.000    3.655    3.655 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     6800    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
    10200    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
    10200    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
    23800    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
     3400    0.268    0.000    0.268    0.000 {built-in method io.open}
    13600    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
     3400    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'cleanup' of 'ImagingDecoder' objects}
     3400    0.150    0.000    0.150    0.000 {method 'close' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
     3400    2.486    0.001    2.486    0.001 {method 'decode' of 'ImagingDecoder' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     3400    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'pixel_access' of 'ImagingCore' objects}
   122400    0.095    0.000    0.095    0.000 {method 'read' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
    10200    0.016    0.000    0.016    0.000 {method 'seek' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
     3400    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {method 'setimage' of 'ImagingDecoder' objects}
     3400    0.006    0.000    0.007    0.000 {method 'sort' of 'list' objects}
```

The trouble maker is this line (toward the end of the report):

```
3400    2.486    0.001    2.486    0.001 {method 'decode' of 'ImagingDecoder' objects}
```

**My questions are as follows:**

1) Am I using the right tools? My knowledge is limited.

2) Why is that step the bottleneck? What kind of operations is taking such a toll on the CPU? I would expect converting images to an RGB array to be rather "fast".

3) Is there a way to improve the speed of my code? I have image data sets of a couple of Gb, and it takes for ever to work with them.

Comment: It may be worth benchmarking different image formats separately. I would expect bmps to get read faster than pngs, for example, since the former doesn't require any decompression.

Comment: 1) to get more precision on the "tottime" column

Comment: 2) My real data set is ~700 Mb so I wanted something more representative but not taking multiple minutes per iteration.
Overall, I take a movie of a glass changing color, then extract all the frames and read the RGB value in different locations to plot the RGB evolution vs time. But i can get Gb of movies transformed into pictures and reading them is painfully long.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a fair amount of CPU to decompress JPEG files, so if you are going to be doing it a lot, I would consider converting your files to a less demanding format, such as [NetPBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) `PPM` (Portable PixMap). You can do that easily with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. This will make a `PPM` format copy of all the JPEG files in the current directory:

```
magick mogrify -format ppm *jpg
```

Then try using the corresponding `PPM` file in place of the JPEG.

---

Another thing you could easily do is parallelise, and do multiple images at once with multiple-threading, or multiprocessing.

---

And finally...

Why do you go through the set 50 times?

Can't you get everything you need in a single pass to avoid decompressing every time?

What are you actually trying to do overall?

Comment: (I commented under your previous comment)
Would you suggest another format than jpeg when I split my movie into images then?

Comment: I don't understand why you are splitting the movie into individual images and saving them to disk in the first place! Why don't you read the movie one frame at a time and extract all the information you need from that frame before reading the next frame. Then, when you get to the end, you will have all the information you need accumulated in memory and be able to produce whatever output you need.

Comment: Well i did not think about that at the time... Splitting in individual images was rather fast with ffmpeg, going at about 4x fps rate but loading with PIL is at least 10x slower. Can I read each frame from an mp4 file with python and do what I was trying to achieve?

Comment: I am no expert on video processing in Python, so please check. I know you can open an ImageSequence in Pillow https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageSequence.html but not sure if that supports MP4. I know OpenCV VideoCapture can read MP4 files easily, and I see this too... https://pypi.org/project/videosequence/  Please check around though, there may be an easier way.